# Is this a Grill door? how do you narrate if some one opens or closes it?

Tags: phrase-requests

[image: picture of sliding metal gate to enter old elevator]

Is this a grill door? if not what do you call this type of doors?
Old elevator systems uses this door. 
If a hinged door is opened, we use "push open", "pull open", "heave open", "dash open", "bang open" etc...
How will you narrate the operation of this type of door.

Comment: I think we called them "elevator gates", back when they actually existed.  It was "slid" open/closed.

Answer (score 4):

Slide open seems apt.
 It is not called a *grille door* but a *scissor gate*:
http://elevation.wikia.com/wiki/Elevator_door_types.
The design is basically the same as that of a grille but the term for it is *scissor gate*:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grille

Comment: However, a narrative story would generally use *grille* or just *gate:* “Once the elevator had ground its way to the fifth floor, he slid the [grille][gate] open and stepped gratefully on to *terra firma.*”

Answer (score -1):

**Accordion doors** is the term used in the UK.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ... for example, [Rochester Door Company](https://rochesterdoorcompany.com/accordion-side-folding-grilles-installation/) (in the US!); [Britannia](https://britanniaretail.com/products/retractable-security-grilles?variant=33063988953122&currency=GBP&utm_medium=product_sync&utm_source=google&utm_content=sag_organic&utm_campaign=sag_organic&gad_source=1&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI-OS0w-u3hAMVjlJBAh2HlwswEAQYASABEgIfAvD_BwE). 'Accordion' sounds better.

Comment: When I Google "accordion doors", it seems to refer to doors which fold and unfold in a zig-zag fashion with corners protruding outwards, perpendicular to the plane of the door ([e.g.](https://www.directdoors.com/collections/concertina-style-folding-doors)), rather than those in the original picture, which open and shut by folding into themselves in the plane of the door without protruding horizontally.

Answer (score -1):

They are not scissor gates as scissor gates are a portable accordian-type barrier - often seen at airports and such - that you can expand or shorten.  These carriage elvator doors are called accordian grille doors

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No, Dexter ... Argot's link clearly shows 'scissor gate' being used for permanent fixtures. So the term is a correct answer, whether or not it is more usually applied to the temporary barriers you mention.